# External table creation in Synapse gives null type column which causes error when connecting with PowerBI

Tags: sql, azure, powerbi, azure-synapse

I'm new to Azure ecosystem and I am trying to build a PowerBI report from processed data stored in Azure Datalake as parquet file.

For the moment I have loaded my parquet file into Synapse serverless SQL database but I have null data type which, I think, causes an error when trying to load the database into PowerBI.

This is my SQL Script :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_file_formats WHERE name = 'SynapseParquetFormat') 
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT [SynapseParquetFormat] 
WITH ( FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources WHERE name = 'test-data_dldevls01_dfs_core_windows_net') 
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [test-data_dldevls01_dfs_core_windows_net] 
    WITH (
        LOCATION = 'abfss://test-data@dldevls01.dfs.core.windows.net' 
    )
GO

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.test (
    [subscriber_id] nvarchar(4000),
    [subscription_id] nvarchar(4000),
    [object] nvarchar(4000),
    [channel] nvarchar(4000),
    [mobile_os] nvarchar(4000),
    [active] nvarchar(4000),
    [active_days] nvarchar(4000),
    [active_hours] nvarchar(4000),
    [created_at] nvarchar(4000),
    [updated_at] nvarchar(4000),
    [active_begin_hour] nvarchar(4000),
    [active_end_hour] nvarchar(4000),
    [object_type] nvarchar(4000),
    [valid_object_pattern] bit,
    [valid_business_rule] bit,
    [mon] bit,
    [tue] bit,
    [wed] bit,
    [thu] bit,
    [fri] bit,
    [sat] bit,
    [sun] bit,
    [subscription_uuid] nvarchar(4000)
    )
    WITH (
    LOCATION = 'refined/subscription/subscriptions.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = [test-data_dldevls01_dfs_core_windows_net],
    FILE_FORMAT = [SynapseParquetFormat]
    )
GO


SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.test
GO
```

Which is working but I dont know why I have null type :

[image]

Then when connecting to PowerBI I have this error : "Expression.Error : Sorry... We were unable to apply the Null field access."

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you generate that `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` statement? It looks auto-generated... I'm curious why-on-earth SQL Server tooling would omit the `NULL`/`NOT NULL` specifier...

Comment: Auto-generated in azure synapse

Comment: I deleted my answer - I had no idea Synapse doesn't allow `NULL`/`NOT NULL` on external table columns - that's just _weird_ to me...

Answer (score 0):

> External table creation in Synapse gives null type column which causes error when connecting with PowerBI.

I tried the same in my environment and created external table from parquet file. It by default pull null values if any value in file is blank.
[image]

Then I Connected it with the Power bi and it got successfully connected.

[image]

When you attempt to access a field or property that has a null value in Power Query or Power BI, an error "Sorry... We were unable to apply the Null field access" usually appears.

**The workaround can be:**

- **Handle null values**: Remove the null values from the data in power bi using the "Remove Rows" or "Remove Errors" transformations. **Or** replace the null values with the other meaningful values you can use the "Replace Values" transformation
- Make sure your data doesn't contain null values.

Comment: can you tell me which data source type do you choose when connecting PowerBI to the synapse SQL table ?

Comment: Azure synapse analytics SQL